# Using with and together in Yii

Tags: yii, paging, relation

I have a grid with paging which displays client data.
Let's say I have a table `Client` with `name`, `lastName` and `address` in it, a table `Phone_Number` which has phone numbers for each of the rows in `Client` and a table `Adress` which has adresses for each client. So each `Client` HAS MANY `Phone_Number`s and HAS MANY `Adress`es.

The point is I'm trying to set a limit to the grid's store read. 
So let's say I set limit = 2. The grid should display only 2 rows per page (2 clients). 
The problem is that if, for example, client1 has two phone numbers, the query will bring two rows, making the grid display only one client. I am aware that setting `together=>false` in the query will solve this. But I'm getting an unknown column error whenever I set `together=>false`.

Here's the code I'm using....

```
Client::model()->with(
      'clientPhoneNumbers',
      'clientPhoneNumbers'.'PhoneNumber',
      'clientAddresses',
      'clientAddresses'.'Address'
)->findAll(array(condition=>(('Address.s_street_name LIKE :queryString') OR ('PhoneNumber.n_number LIKE :queryString')), params=>$params, order=>$order, limit=>$limit,together=>false));
```

If I do this, I get an error like: `Column not found: Address.s_street_name` . However, if I set `together=>true`, it works just "fine".

I found a solution to this problem by doing the query like this....

```
$with = array(
      'clientPhoneNumbers',
      'clientPhoneNumbers'.'PhoneNumber'=>array(condition=>('PhoneNumber.n_number LIKE :queryString'), params=>array(':queryString'=>$queryString)),
      'clientAddresses',
      'clientAddresses'.'Address'=>array(condition=>('Address.s_street_name LIKE :queryString'), params=>array(':queryString'=>$queryString))
);

Client::model()->findAll(array(with=>$with, order=>$order, limit=>$limit,together=>false));
```

The problem is that if I do it like this, the condition is something like this

```
(('Address.s_street_name LIKE :queryString') AND ('PhoneNumber.n_number LIKE :queryString'))
```

and I need it to be like this

```
(('Address.s_street_name LIKE :queryString') OR ('PhoneNumber.n_number LIKE :queryString')).
```

Any ideas ?

Keep in mind that the names of the relations and tables are not the actual names. The models and relations where created using Gii

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. this is how I would try it.

```
<?php
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array('clientPhoneNumbers', 'clientAddresses');
$criteria->together = true;
$criteria->addCondition(array('Address.s_street_name LIKE :queryString', 'PhoneNumber.n_number LIKE :queryString'), 'OR');    
$criteria->params = array(':queryString' => $queryString);
$criteria->limit = $limit;
$criteria->order = $order;

$result = Client::model()->findAll($criteria);
?>
```

Also, I think [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria/#c4414) describes a case similar to yours. Note that he/she is updating the [condition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#condition-detail) parameter explicitly, but IMO doing it with the [addCondition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail) method is more readable.

Comment: Does it persist if you remove the limit?

Answer (score 0):

use criteria with join statement.

```
public function test()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->alias = 'i';
    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);     
    .........
            .........

    $criteria->join= 'JOIN phoneNUmbers d ON (i.id=d.id)';

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'clients ASC',
        ),
    ));
}
```

Alternately use DAO to prepare and execute your own query and return data in the format you wish.

Or you can use CSQLDataProvier. the last 2 options give you more control over the SQL statement